# Where can I get FlexAntTasks.jar

Tags: apache-flex

I need FlexAntTasks.jar for Ant to execute flex unit tests 
the one i am currently working with is Beta version Is there any release for it?

Answer (score 1):

The Flex Ant Tasks are included in the Flex SDK.

Comment: to be more specific: it's located under \sdks\4.0.0\ant\lib and it's called flexTasks.jar